# using OpenCL C++ Wrapper in windows with gcc

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, gcc, opencl

OK, so I tried to learn some openCL and I'm using Windows, I don't want to buy a Visual Studio license however and opted for gcc (latest mingw installer). I also like objects very much and wanted to use the c++ wrapper api. So after I verified my setup works with a minimal example using CL/cl.h I changed to CL/cl.hpp and tried to compile an empty program:

```
#define __NO_STD_VECTOR // Use cl::vector instead of STL version
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

using namespace cl;

int main() {

}
```

It gave me tons of errors:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g    -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include"  -c C:\Users\Rialgar\CodeBlocksProjects\OpenCL_FirstSteps\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
In file included from C:\Users\Rialgar\CodeBlocksProjects\OpenCL_FirstSteps\main.cpp:3:0:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:5929:9: Warnung: Bezeichner »static_assert« wird in C++11 zum Schlüsselwort [-Wc++0x-compat]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Funktion »cl_int cl::copy(IteratorType, IteratorType, cl::Buffer&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:5157:9: Fehler: »stdext« wurde nicht deklariert
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:5157:48: Fehler: expected primary-expression before »*« token
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:5157:49: Fehler: expected primary-expression before »>« token
In file included from C:\Users\Rialgar\CodeBlocksProjects\OpenCL_FirstSteps\main.cpp:3:0:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, T27, T28, T29, T30, T31>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:5929:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:5929:216: Anmerkung: (mit »-fpermissive« wird G++ den Code akzeptieren, aber die Verwendung eines nicht deklarierten Namens ist veraltet)
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, T27, T28, T29, T30, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:6297:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, T27, T28, T29, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:6657:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, T27, T28, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:7009:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, T27, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:7353:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:7689:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:8017:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:8337:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:8649:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:8953:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:9249:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:9537:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:9817:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:10089:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:10353:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:10609:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:10857:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:11097:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:11329:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:11553:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:11769:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:11977:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:12177:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:12369:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:12553:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:12729:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:12897:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:13057:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, T3, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:13209:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, T2, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:13353:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, T1, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:13489:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp: In Konstruktor »cl::detail::functionImplementation_<T0, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType, cl::detail::NullType>::functionImplementation_(const FunctorType&)«:
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include/CL/cl.hpp:13617:216: Fehler: es gibt keine Argumente für »static_assert«, die von einem Templateparameter abhängen, weshalb eine Deklaration von »static_assert« verfügbar sein muss [-fpermissive]
```

(Sorry for the german error messages, I was not able to change the language of gcc, yet) As the first one is a warning concerning C++11 I figured I could ignore it for now and hope for fixes in future versions of OpenCL. The first Error message says stdext was not defined, so I Googled it: the results say stdext is a MS specific namespace.

I did not dig into the other errors, yet, but they say "static_assert" has no arguments depending on a template parameter and therefore a declaration of "static_assert" needs to be available.

My Question: Does this mean I cannot use the c++ wrapper under windows without MSVC, or is there a workaround e.g. an alternative cl.hpp?

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: add at least `-std=c++0x -pedantic -Wall`. but if you're trying to compile ms code with g++, well good luck

Comment: "I don't want to buy a Visual Studio license" Why you don't use Express Version, which is free?

Comment: @ErikEsTT: because I did not know of it and the Microsoft homepage was not very eager to tell me about it, I thought there must be something, but I somehow did'nt find it. Thanks a lot. (I still don't like to use it, but there seems to be no way around except basic c version of openCL)

Comment: Another way to get your feet dirty with OpenCL is to use WebCL.  See http://webcl.nokiaresearch.com/. You can compile and run kernel from  browser.